# Should Dispose() be called on ReaderWriterLockSlim lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading

A project that I work on was analyzed by a commercial analysis tool.  It flagged our  implementations of ReaderWriterLockSlim as potential sources of memory leaks because we didn't call the Dispose() method.

I've never seen this method called on this lock:  either in code I've worked on or code examples I learned from.  Should Dispose() be called?  What if it's disposed while a thread still needs it?  Is this possible?

Here's a sample of how we currently use it - no Dispose():

```
    Public Class Test 
    {

    private ReaderWriterLockSlim _lookupLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

            public IDictionary<int, SomeObject> GetAll()
            {
                _lookupLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    if (X == null || X.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Do Something...;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _lookupLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }

                return Something...;
            }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it has a Dispose() method so that tool is going to complain.  What you have to weigh is the cost of you actually calling Dispose().  It is a very high one, you *have* to make sure that *all* threads that use the RWLS have exited.  This can be very hard to achieve.  The simple way is to just leave it up to the garbage collector, it never gets it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does need to be disposed.

Mostly a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is used to protect a static resource, so will be a static instance that doesn't need to be disposed.

But in your case (one `ReaderWriterLockSlim` per instance), you would need to make your class `IDisposable`, and dispose the `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Or maybe a better alternative is to use an ordinary lock (i.e. Monitor) to protect instance resources rather than a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`.  There's probably not much performance difference, it makes your code simpler, and it avoids you needing to make your class IDisposable.

Framework classes like `ConcurrentDictionary` use ordinary locks.

Comment: I am using it to protect a static resource(s) and have one instance of the lock per class (I updated my question to reflect this).  Is there any risk to disposing the lock because a thread is dependent on it?

Comment: If you're protecting a static resource, surely the _lookupLock field needs to be static, in which case you don't need to dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, try to inherit from IDisposable. Look at this class declaration as an example.

Change your declaration to this, and of course, add in the rest of your existing code.

```
Public Class Test : IDisposable
{

}
```

How I would declare it, example below.

```
public class WriteLock : IDisposable
{
   ReaderWriterLockSlim _rwlock;
   public WriteLock(ReaderWriterLockSlim rwlock ) 
   { 
      _rwlock = rwlock;
      _rwlock.EnterWriteLock(); 
   }
   public void Dispose()
   {
      _rwlock.ExitWriteLock(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: The class declaration is standard: Public Class Something{}.  It's methods utilize the locks like I posted.

Comment: Then you need to add : IDisposable like the example I have shown you have a private method not a Class.. show the Class Declaration please

Comment: I updated my answer to show the Class.  I don't want to use a wrapper class to manage this, yet.  Just want to know if calling Dispose() on the lock is something that needs to be done.

Comment: So change your code to look like this and test it... to see if the memory leak goes away. Public Class Test :IDisposable

Comment: Shouldn't `Test.Dispose()` just turn around and call `_lookupLock.Dispose()`?

Comment: not the Class does not Implement I Disposable
If _lookupLock Implments IDisposable you could do ((IDisposable)_lookupLock).Dispose(); you would need to test that by debugging you will know when you compile it / run it if it will work or not..

Comment: LOOK AT WHAT @JOE has written / explained below.. please try what has been suggested and then report back if you are still getting the error or not.. Thanks

Comment: I was not getting an error.  It was flagged as a potential memory leak (mentioned in original post).